# Converting curl request to android HttpURLConnection Post Request

Tags: android, curl, https

Hi iam developing an android app in which i used mailchimp service.In short
I have no knowledge of curl and i want to convert the following curl request to httpurlconnection post request.
Any help would appreciated and thanks in advanced.Here is the curl code

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/57afe96172/members' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"email_address":"urist.mcvankab+3@freddiesjokes.com", "status":"subscribed"}' \
--include
```

> i coded it and below is my android code but in the logcat i get 400
>   Bad Request

```
try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                JSONObject info= new JSONObject();
                info.put("email_address",email);
                info.put("status","subscribed");

                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(info.toString());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                int HttpResult =urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();

                    System.out.println("  "+sb.toString());

                }else{
                    System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                }
                Log.e("authkey==> ",apiKey+"");
                //  InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("URL","Error in URL Connection");
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                Log.d("URL","Error in URL Connection,Connection Closed");
            }
```

Comment: you really should find this easy to use on of the many http clients out there.

Comment: Did not get you sir.?